# Помогите связать 2 пользователей в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text="Активные игры")
async def akv_game(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите игру:',reply_markup=genmarkup())#клава с лобби

#к каждой кнопке с лобби дописываю продолжение
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def stoptopupcall(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    sqldata = db.teg() 
    sortdata = [] 
    for i in sqldata:
        sortdata.append(i[0])

    if callback_query.data in sortdata: 
        userinfo =  db.kbdate(calls = callback_query.data)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f'Описание: {userinfo[3]}\nСумма: {userinfo[2]}',reply_markup = game_kb)#в клаве 2 кнопки  - принять(call_data = "yes'),отмена(call_data = "no')
        own_ids = userinfo[1] #id создателя лобби
       
#Дальше я тупой 
# как сделать так чтобы другой пользователь нажал на одну из игр ->нажал принять и у них обоих началась игра именно в этом лобби
```

Пользователь (1) создал игру и мне нужно чтобы пользователь (2) нажал на кнопку принять и у них началась игра

Comment: Сделай словарь, можно даже глобальный, и записывай их туда

Comment: как мне понять кто нажал на кнопку?

Comment: Ну к примеру ключ этот тот создал а значение тот кто нажал(присоединилися)

Comment: теперь по нажатию на так называемое лобби я получаю id создателя и нажавшего-теперь не работает callback на кнопку принять

Comment: Я же не экстрасенс, я не знаю что вы там накодили.

Comment: все кнопка тыкается, теперь последняя проблема как передать в кнопку данные из прошлого callbacka(из кода выше)

Comment: `state.proxy()` нет?

Comment: предлагаете состояние?

Comment: нет, просто запиши в стейт, запускать его не обязательно. Ну или запиши в тот же словарь